# find ifream source when create link from database

Tags: javascript

i writing this code to fetch links from database,after clicking url's can show to iframe, but i can't get iframe real src:

```
if ( mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) 
{
   echo"<li><a href='#' class='alink'>".$key.'</a>';
   echo'<ul>';
   while($qsql=mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        echo "<li ><a href='{$qsql['ModuleAddress']}  target='links' class='alink'>".$qsql['ModuleTitle'].'</a></li>';
   echo'</ul>';
   echo'</li>';
}
```

my html link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="GetIFrameUrl();">
```

my iframe is:

```
<iframe width="100%" id="links" name='links' frameborder="0" src='arm.html' style="border: none;padding: 0;margin: 0;"> </iframe>
```

my js is:

```
function GetIFrameUrl()
                {
                    var control = document.getElementById("links");
                    alert("iframe source = " + control.src);
                }
```

Comment: Your code is fine, given the `<iframe>` element really exists. Check the value of `control` (in firebug, or chrome developer tools, for example)

Comment: Define "iframe real src". Do you want an absolute URI but get a relative URI? Do you want the current URI but get the original URI? Something else?

Comment: i cant find witch value is changed in firebug